# Localization in android application

Tags: android, localization

There is question.

I am working on localization (locale language specification) in my sample android app.

following this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

What i am doing, created three value folders.

```
1-values-fr
      string.xml  

 2-values-de
      string.xml

 3-values-nl
      string.xml
```

in default values `string.xml` having three strings

```
<string name="btn">OK</string>
    <string name="btn_back">Back</string>
    <string name="btn_next">Next</string>
```

for values-fr:-

```
 <string name="btn">bien</string>
    <string name="btn_back">arrière</string>
    <string name="btn_next">suivant</string>
```

Now i am converting my english word to french words and putted them in to `values-fr` `string.xml`

I think this very headache work translate every english word into french or other language and then put in to `string.xml`.

**Here is question FOCUS:- This is only the way to do this or we have some other ways**

Comment: so you want to translate words without translation?

Comment: yes if any option available which automatic convert english to any language.

Comment: no, it doesn't exist, sorry

Comment: ok thanks means i have to create string.xml for each language right?and only i need to translate these words.

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically translate your strings.xml using Translator Toolkit. You can read about it [here](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.it/2012/03/localize-your-apps-and-content-more.html).

If you just want to see the values in different languages in one table then you can check Sequoyah plugin. It has Sequoyah Android Localization Editor tool that shows all string keys and respective values in different languages in one table. The information about Sequoyah project is located here: http://eclipse.org/sequoyah Installation guide is here: http://eclipse.org/sequoyah/downloads/index.php#update_site.

Comment: Thanks Yury..translation is not problem ,problem is this for each language i need to create separate string.xml..

Comment: Using this tool you need just appload your string.xml file and then the tool will translate it in any language.

Comment: ohh is it.ok Yury i ll give it try.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [OneSky](http://www.oneskyapp.com) to solve the problem you mentioned.

It’s very easy.

- Upload your English .xml file
- Translate (you can translate online using ouronline editor or order machine/ human translation)
- When the translation process is completed, the system will generate all the .xml files in different languages for you automatically
- You can download all the translation as a single zip file. It already includes the necessary folder structure that can be directly used for your app

Our platform is free to use, unless you decide to order translation service from us.

Disclaimer: I’m an employee at OneSky